# how to add acknowledgments in r package

Tags: r-package

A non-technical question

I have been helped by a few folks (here on SO) with my questions and would like to acknowledge them in my package.

How can I do that, should I add them with `ctb` (contributor) role, or is there another role available for people who might not have provided actual code/content but have helped in tackling issues.

Thanks

Comment: When I use code from SO, I always put the link to the answer that helped me as a comment in my code. If some people really helped you a lot, contact them and ask them what they prefer.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion!